# How to reset Excel Vertical Scroll Bar length (without closing, then re-opening Workbook)

Tags: vba, excel

Part of my program pastes several columns of data in a worksheet, then removes duplicate values in each column (with the variable range to search for duplicate values called rngDelete), then counts the number of unique values. After getting the count values, I delete all the rows in rngDelete.

But I notice that after deleting the rows, my vertical scroll bar length still remains the same, i.e. the same length as when I had data in rngDelete rows. It is true that re-opening the worksheet will reset the scroll bar length, but I was wondering if there is a way to force this to happen upon program runtime completion?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/433658/121933

Comment: Brian, you want to put in @Jon Crowell so he gets a notification.  (at)Brian Mustang is not needed because this is your question.

Comment: @Jon Crowell: dcromley's answer helped, but thank you for directing to this post. I read it and Microsoft's support document and I think I have a better understanding of the process now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excuting the following resets the lastcell and does what you want.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeLastCell)
```

Comment: Just because I just discovered this, if your sheet is protected, then this may throw an error saying it can't be done with protection turned on. Very strange, and would happen with the exact same file on a colleague's computer, but not on mine.